# Can StackExchange.Redis be used to store POCO?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

I am trying to evaluate Redis by using two well known C# drivers [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) and [StackExchange](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis). Unfortunately I cannot use ServiceStack because it's not free. Now I'm trying StackExchange.

Does anybody know whether with StackExchange.Redis I can persist POCOs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

StackExchange.Redis can store [Redis Strings](http://redis.io/topics/data-types), which are binary safe. That means, that you can easily serialize a POCO using the serialization technology of your choice and put it in there.

The following example uses the .NET [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx). Please note that you have to decorate your class with the `SerializableAttribute` to make this work.

Example set operation:

```
PocoType somePoco = new PocoType { Id = 1, Name = "YouNameIt" };
string key = "myObject1";
byte[] bytes;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, somePoco);
    bytes = stream.ToArray();
}

db.StringSet(key, bytes);
```

Example get operation:

```
string key = "myObject1";
PocoType somePoco = null;
byte[] bytes = (byte[])db.StringGet(key);

if (bytes != null)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        somePoco = (PocoType) new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a good example,  it please please please don't use BknaryFormatter. Ever. /cc @Duke

Comment: @Frank BF is *terrible* at versioning and refactoring, and is platform-specific. I would strongly recommend something designed for tolerant multi-platform work; xml, json, or for binary: protobuf, etc.

Comment: @MarcGravell Is Newtonsoft.Json is a good alternative for BinaryFormatter?

Comment: @Burak it is a good and mature serializer, for sure. It depends on your objectives. If you want to minimize bandwidth and server-side impact (CPU, memory), is use something like protobuf-net or bond. If that isn't important: json is fine - it has the advantage of being human readable, at the price of size.